# Why are ViewPropertyAnimatorRT missing in API 29?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to use this class to render the animation in the word thread,

But now I can't find this class, who can tell me why this class was deleted？

Answer (score 0):

question why it was removed should be answered by someone from Android team. probably they just refactored some internal animation utils due to new possibilities...

you can always copy-paste this class source and paste into your project (with different name just in case), you probably should find workaround for `FallbackLUTInterpolator` usage (or just remove related items, supplying different `Interpolator` in this place, eg. linear)

[SOURCE](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/57caeb5/core/java/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimatorRT.java)